# Push huge list in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, doc

I have a huge list of stores name in (.doc) file and I want to store these names in mysql DB The solution which I thought was to create an array of this list & by looping insert them in DB..
But I don’t know how to push this list in php array..

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some data of .doc file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the word doc as a plain text (.txt) file. Read the file in a line at a time, and insert into the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you can use [WV](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/wv.htm).

Else you can use [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) or [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) to pull the text out.

Then you'll still need to put the text into a proper `Array()` and you'll probably use some sort of REGEX to do that.